# Configuring asserts in production in Dart

Tags: dart

In production asserts are stripped away in Dart.

However, I would like to configure this behaviour. Is this possible?

In PHP you can configure this with assert_options: http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert-options.php

Ideally, I would like to be able to log all the failed assertions that happen in production.

Comment: What is the intention? Shouldn't they be normal exceptions then? You could just use your custom assert function that throws in case the expression returns `false`. There might be options though, but I think it's not entirely clear how this will turn out in Dart2.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be plans to provide that in Dart 2

> dart2js has --enable-asserts, just like the VM (also --enable-asserts, ending in s).
>   It is just not advertised.

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32255

There seem still be ongoing discussions how to make this available in Dart 2 final https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32442

---

In Dart 1 there is the `--checked` flag that enables asserts